# iOS-Charts Float to Integer YAxis

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm building a chart using iOS-charts
[image: IOS CHART]

I'm trying to convert the floats into int, but iOS-charts only allows for Floats in the data entry:

```
      let result = ChartDataEntry(value: Float(month), xIndex: i)
```

Does anyone know the method for making sure only ints are used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to adjust the `NSNumberFormatter`...

Example:

```
yAxis.valueFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
yAxis.valueFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
```

`NSNumberFormatter` is a very powerful class, you can do much much more with it. :-)

Comment: Thanks for you help. I tried this, but sadly it didn't work. Can't find any information on the repo either :(

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney It does work. What have you tried? Maybe you are setting the wrong valueFormatter `property`? The different components have that property separate

Comment: You are right, sorry!  I added: self.lineChartholder.leftAxis.valueFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        self.lineChartholder.leftAxis.valueFormatter?.minimumFractionDigits = 0

Comment: This doesn't quite work. If the axis range is too small, e.g. 5-8, with 7 gridlines, then it shows 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7 in the axis.

Answer (score 33):

For Swift 3.0 and Charts 3.0 you need to enable and set granularity for the axis.

Example:

```
barChart.leftAxis.granularityEnabled = true
barChart.leftAxis.granularity = 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. However, the y-axis labels will round when displaying small numbers, so if you are charting, say 1 or 2, the chart will display 0 twice. (See here: [Force BarChart Y axis labels to be integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753540/force-barchart-y-axis-labels-to-be-integers))

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = false
chartDataSet.valueFormatter = numberFormatter
// Converting to Int for small numbers rounds weird
//barChartView.rightAxis.valueFormatter = numberFormatter
//barChartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = numberFormatter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, it worked nicely for me

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .NoStyle
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "es_CL")
BarChartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = formatter
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift4.2 ; Xcode 10.0 :

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = false
barChart.leftAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter.init(formatter: numberFormatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

NSNumberFormatter gives duplicate values because it just convert decimal to integer. You can use below solution, It will not give any duplicate values. Also you can set minimum and maximum as per the requirement of the chart. Below worked for me as per my requirement.

```
        barChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = max(0.0, 0.0)
        barChart.leftAxis.axisMaximum = min(10.0, barChart.data!.yMax + barChart.data!.yMin)
        barChart.leftAxis.labelCount = Int(barChart.leftAxis.axisMaximum - barChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum)
        barChart.leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = false
```