# Setting iOS-Charts Float to Integer YAxis

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I tried setting yAxis to integer using NSNumberFormatter,

```
yAxis.valueFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
yAxis.valueFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
```

but the problem here is I am getting duplicate yAxis values - 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 and 5. 
How this can be eliminated?

[image]

These are the issues I am facing. I tried setting

```
    barChart.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 5.0
    barChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
    barChart.leftAxis.customAxisMin = 0
    barChart.leftAxis.customAxisMax = 5.0
```

but not helping any suggestions?

Comment: This Question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318858/ios-charts-float-to-integer-yaxis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be avoided, because you don't allow fraction digit.

`minimumFractionDigits = 0` means no decimal if possible, like 2.1 and 2.0, they will result in 2.1 and 2 ( if maximumFractionDigits = 1)

You need to give the information what's the raw value and what's the value of maximumFractionDigits

**EDIT:**

the y axis label is calculated by default via `internal func computeAxisValues`

it calculate the interval based on your max and min value, and the label count.

if `_yAxis.isForceLabelsEnabled` is enabled, then it will read `labelCount` and just use (max-min)/(labelCount-1) to calculate the interval. It is disabled by default.

When isForceLabelsEnabled is false, it has a small algorithm to calculate what's the proper way to get a good looking number.

Take a look at `internal func computeAxisValues` to find out what meets your need.

**Update** for your second part of question:

1. you should not touch axisMaximum nor min
2. enable `forceLabelsEnabled`
3. change `yAxis.labelCount` to 6 or 5 or whatever you like
4. enable `xAxis.wordWrapEnabled`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. I don't want to display decimal on my y-Axis. I'll just give you an example. I need to display rating on my yAxis, the rating may varies from 0 to 5, but the value can be [2.1, 4.3, 5, 3.5, 3, 2, 1], something like this. My yAxis should not have decimal showing up. I tried setting             barChart.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 5.0
            barChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
            barChart.leftAxis.customAxisMin = 0
            barChart.leftAxis.customAxisMax = 5.0
but not helping.

Comment: answer updated. you should use `leftAxis.customAxisMin/Max` by the way.

Comment: it's not working. Any work around? Updated the question.

Comment: answer updated. BTW, you should be able and should read `computeAxisValues`, it gives what all you need

Comment: I have one more question. Is there a way to not to show the value when we have '0' as rating.

Comment: let us say I get rating as '0' since drawValuesEnabled is enabled it shows '0' on top of the x-axis. Is their a way to avoid it? If value is zero then don't display anything, else whatever the rating we get.

Comment: simply override drawValues to ignore 0

Comment: you mean do I need to subclass 'ChartDataRendererBase' and override drawValues?

Comment: Just the sub class you are using

Comment: Hi.. I need more information on usage of iOS-Chart, is it possible to have some other way of communication? If I get your email or something.

Comment: Sorry, I just answer questions on github and SO when I have time. But you could try read the code. They give all the information and try http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

Comment: Thats Ok, np.. I keep posting questions here.. :)

Comment: For ignoring '0', can you please brief me, the class where I am drawing the chart is UIViewController's subclass.

Comment: take a look at the Y axis renderer drawValues

Comment: OK.. will check and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92967/discussion-between-ash-and-wingzero).