# iOS Charts custom labels: integer values on Bubble Chart

Tags: ios, swift, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I want to show the values displayed inside the bubbles as whole number Ints. For example: instead of "22.0" I just want "22".

[The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34614478/6830560) doesn't work with the new iOS Charts because it requires an `IValueFormatter` instead of a `NumberFormatter`:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = false
chartData.setValueFormatter(numberFormatter)
```

Error Message:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NumberFormatter' to expected argument type 'IValueFormatter?'
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new charts, you still use numberformatter and then just convert at the end. Reference the code below.

```
let format = NumberFormatter()
format.generatesDecimalNumbers = false   
let formatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)
chartData.leftAxis.valueFormatter = (formatter as? IAxisValueFormatter)
```

Hope this helps!